# imagecopyresized creates zero bits image

Tags: php, image

I'm using the slim plugin to upload files to my server.  The first part of the code works fine for .jpg files, I thought it would be easy to do for .png files too just by changing jpeg for png in the code but it doesn't work, it creates a file with a file size of zero bits.  I'm sure it's a quick fix when you know how but I've wasted ages trying to get this to work - please help me?

```
        $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($output_filename2);
        imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0,0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
        imagejpeg($thumb, $output_filename_new, $jpeg_quality);


        $source = imagecreatefrompng($output_filename2);
        imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0,0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
        imagepng($thumb,  $output_filename_new, $jpeg_quality);
```

Comment: What is the value of `$jpeg_quality`? `imagepng()` needs values `0`-`9`, but maybe if the quality is set to bad value, it produces empty image?

Comment: use getimagesize($source); to check that the source is existing and check if $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height are set

Answer (score 0):

Me being silly, sorry.

It was this line that I should have changed depending on source image type.  Eeeejit!

```
$source = imagecreatefrompng($output_filename2);
```

could be changed to:

```
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($output_filename2);
```

Etc.  Hope this helps someone.